# Yii2 get url based on module base url

Tags: php, module, frameworks, yii2

I have multi modules application.
I want to create `url` based on `module baseurl`

For example:

```
$link=\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( 'dish/getNew' );
```

i want:
 `'/web/modules/kitchen/dish/getNew'` and the function gave me `'/web/dish/getNew'`

Comment: Please format your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Url` helper's `toRoute()` method:

```
\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['Controller/Action','key'=>'value']);
```

Above code creates URL based on your current module.

Output would be something like:

```
.../index.php?r=ModuleName/Controller/Action&key=value
```

If you want to keep using `createUrl()`, you must also mention your module name statically like below:

```
\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['moduleName/Controller/Action','key'=>'value']);
```

Above code generates the same output.